# Maze path finder in Java

Tags: java, recursion, path, maze

I'm trying to solve the Maze using recursion. In the following piece of code, MazeCoord is a programmer created type that stores a coordinate type location. The format is MazeCoord(int x, int y). My program when compiled right now, reaches some parts of the method and ignores the other and hence says "No Path Found" in all cases and only stores the start location in the LinkedList mazePath. 
There's a commented out part in the search() method that was another way I was trying out but I'm pretty sure that it is wrong and not the way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Recursion code:

/**
Returns the path through the maze. First element is starting location, and
last element is exit location.  If there was not path, or if this is called
before search, returns empty list.

@return the maze path
*/

```
public LinkedList<MazeCoord> getPath() {
       return mazePath; 
}
```

/**
Find a path through the maze if there is one.  Client can access the
path found via getPath method.
@return whether path was found.
*/

```
public boolean search() {  
       currentLoc = new MazeCoord(startLoc.getRow(), startLoc.getCol());
       visitedPath = new boolean[mazeData.length][mazeData[0].length];

       mazePath=new LinkedList<MazeCoord>();

       if(hasWallAt(startLoc) || hasWallAt(endLoc)){    
       return false;
       }
       else{
           mazePath.add(currentLoc);
           return appendToSearch(currentLoc.getRow(), currentLoc.getCol());
       }

       /**
       System.out.println("try1");
       mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(startLoc.getRow(), startLoc.getCol()));
       boolean searchResult = appendToSearch(numRows()-1, numCols()-1);

       System.out.println("test: " + searchResult);
       System.out.println("test2: row, col --> " + (numRows()-1) + " , " +  (numCols()-1));
       System.out.println("test3: wallValue:" + hasWallAt(new  MazeCoord(numRows()-1,numCols()-1)));

       if(searchResult){
           System.out.println("try2");
           mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(numRows()-1, numCols()-1));
       }
       return searchResult;
       */
   }
```

/**Helper function for the search() method that will perform 
      the actual recursion to obtain the path through the maze
      @param row the row for the currentLoc
      @param col the column for the currentLoc
      @return true iff a path is available
    */

```
    private boolean appendToSearch(int row, int col) {


        //Check if within the maze
        if((row - 1 < 0) || (col - 1 < 0) || (row + 1 > numRows()) || (col + 1 >  numCols())){
            return false;
        }
        //Check if the position is the exit location
        if(row == endLoc.getRow() && col == endLoc.getCol()){
            mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(row, col));
            return false;
        }
        //Check for Wall
        if(hasWallAt(new MazeCoord(row, col))){
            return false;
        }
        //Check if the position has already been visited
        if(visitedPath[row][col]){
            return false;
        }
        //If all pass --> add to visitedPath
        visitedPath[row][col]=true;

        //Check to the Right
        if(appendToSearch(row, col + 1)){
           mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(row, col + 1));
           return true;
        }
        //Check Downwards
        else if(appendToSearch(row + 1, col)){
            mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(row + 1, col));
            return true;
        }
        //Check to the Left
        else if(appendToSearch(row, col - 1)){
            mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(row, col - 1));
            return true;
        }
        //Check Upwards
        else if(appendToSearch(row - 1, col)){
            mazePath.add(new MazeCoord(row - 1, col));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I would like to suggest you [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which explains one of the most common pathfinding algorithms out there.

A short tutorial you could also follow can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)
In my opinion this tutorial will fit well with your requirements, since it takes a grid as an example.

It's not required to use a recursive function to perform a pathfinding algorithm.
What you could do could be to hold two lists: one of already *'checked'* cells/tiles and another one of those which have not yet.

Successively you will start from the point where you want to begin the path and will check for all the cells/tiles which can be reached from this point, like:

```
void addCells(Point current) {
   // Left
   if (emptyAndNotChecked(current.x-1,current.y)) // Checking for walls here
      cellsToCheck.add(new Point(x-1,y)) // Adding this cell to the list
   // Right
   if (emptyAndNotChecked(current.x+1,current.y))
      cellsToCheck.add(new Point(x+1,y))
   // Top
   if (emptyAndNotChecked(current.x,current.y+1))
      cellsToCheck.add(new Point(x,y+1))
   // Bottom
   if (emptyAndNotChecked(current.x,current.y-1))
      cellsToCheck.add(new Point(x,y-1))
}
```

Where `emptyAndNotChecked()` just checks whether the given position is not a wall and has not already been checked.
Of course you can also perform a diagonal check!

At this point you want to find the next cell/tile from where you wanna add more cells, you can do this by checking all the "unchecked" cells/tiles and by applying to each one of the a of "weight" function which will give you the best cell/tile for a given destination, a basic implementation could be this:

```
float weight(Point current,Point end) {
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(current.x-end.x,2)+Math.pow(current.y-end.y,2));
}
```

This function will allow you to find the most suitable cell/tile to navigate to, once found it (the one with the lowest weight), you move to this one and call again the first function to add more cells/tiles.

You will stop when the cell/tile you moved to is the destination or when calling the `addCells()` you don't add any new cell/tile.

Of course this is just a basic way to do that and there are a lot of improvements that can be applied.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for your response. I will check out the links you provided. About the recursion though, I have to find the path using recursion, it's a requirement so I have no way around it. I feel like my thinking for the code is correct, just the way I'm implementing it is off. I was using a Boolean 2D array for the points that have been visited or not check. It's called visitedPath in my code. Do you know why some parts of my code are unreachable?

Comment: Hello, when you check the other directions you use `return true` if one of these works, but instead you shouldn't return otherwise some of these directions will never be checked!
You can declare a flag `boolean added = false` and then, for each direction you check, you set this to true if `appendToSearch()` returns true, then at the end of the function you simply write `return added;`

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for that tip. I'll give that a try as well.

Comment: Hi @Luke , update on the code. I made the changes you suggested. It works but only for one iteration of the code. Also, the search() method still doesn't reach the if statement condition, it straight away goes to the else statement condition.

Comment: Are you talking about this if statement: ` if(hasWallAt(startLoc) || hasWallAt(endLoc))`? If so it should be fine that the code is entering into the else statement!
May I ask you why you have yo use recursion to do this? It could lead you to a huge stack in calls if the maze is big enough!